# Symfony3 - Phone Number

Tags: symfony

I know there are many ways to save a phone number in a DB but for some reason I decided to save it as 3 separate fields. Area Code, Exchange and Last4 (US number). What I am now trying to do is when I display this number in a form to the user I want it to be in one field instead of the 3 separate fields. I would probably like to reformat it in the xxx-xxx-xxxx format but I want that field to also be able to accept numerous types of formats in case the user enters it different. Ie. 1-xxx-xxx-xxxx or xxxxxxxxxx or 1xxxxxxxxxx or (xxx)xxx-xxxx and other variations. I'm just looking for some direction on where to start with this? Should I be looking at using a DataTransformer? or can this all be done somehow in validations? Don't know if this makes any difference but the number is in a OneToMany relationship with "Users" and I built my form using the FormCollection instructions (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Again my biggest question right now is how do I get the 3 fields merged into one for the user to see in the form and then what do I use to split it back up and persist it to the database?

Comment: Data transformers is what you want.

Comment: a simpler solutions would be a javascript plugin that does that for you. and revalidate in your backend if you'd like.

Comment: You may check out https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle its a bridge for googles libphonenumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Guys! I preferred Rufinus's response so far and so far have switched my entity to store the phone number in a single field as required by phone-number-bundle.